# Converting from time to timestamp in moment js?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am using ionic time picker in my app and when a time is selected from this plugin it gives the timestamp in callback.

For ex : if time selected is `09:30 AM` the timestamp in callback is `34200` and to convert this timestamp to its original value i.e `09:30 AM` I am doing this

`moment.unix(callback).utc().format('hh:mm A');`

now I have to reverse this i.e I have time as `09:30 AM` and I want to get timestamp from it as `34200` using moment js.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX timestamp `34200` its basically the date `1970-01-01 09:30 AM` so to convert it back you need to set the correct date since this information is lost when you format using `hh:mm A`.

```js
var callback = 34200;
var asHHMM = moment.unix(callback).utc().format('hh:mm A');
var asUNIX = moment.utc(asHHMM, 'hh:mm A').year(1970).month(0).date(1).unix();
console.log(callback, asHHMM, asUNIX);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```